# Does version 12.03 exist?

Tags: release-management

I want to know whether Ubuntu 12.03  exists? If yes please provide me the download link.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 12.03. Do you mean 12.04?

Comment: I say the same as A.B. only that I put a link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29 **;-)**

Comment: Yes, all right. I'm still learning to be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.03 does not exist. A new version of Ubuntu is usually released every 6 months, in April (*.04) and in October (*.10). The closest version would be **Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise Pangolin)**, and it can be downloaded from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/).

Another interesting thing to note is that since the version number is based on the year and month of release, when the target deadline can't be met, the release date might be pushed back slightly later, as was the case with [**Ubuntu 6.06 LTS (Dapper Drake)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_6.06_LTS_.28Dapper_Drake.29).